# sed: -e expression #1, char 44: unterminated address regex

Tags: sed

**PROBLEM:**

I'm writing a script to configure Debian installs..... I need to comment out the line in sources.list for the DVD, I'm trying to use sed, I know how to delete the line or lines but I want to comment it out instead.

What I have is this:

```
sed -i '/deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.4.0 _S/s/^/#/' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

but it gives this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 44: unterminated address regex
```

I'm guessing that it's the bracket that is the trouble.

**QUESTION:**

What is the trouble here and how do you fix the command and/or is there some other way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
  sed -i '/deb cdrom:\[Debian GNU\/Linux 9\.4\.0 _S/s/^/#/' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

- we need to escape the `[`, `/` and `.` in the search pattern, `/` because it's the delimiter, and `[` and `.` because they are regexp operators.

Answer (score 0):

Since the search string is a constant, with the presence of regex metacharacters being the irritants, you could also do it as follows:

```
 awk -i inplace 'index($0, "deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.4.0 _S"){$0 = "#" $0}1' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

You're in luck if you have access to GNU awk `4.1.0` or above for the in-place editing effect. OTW, you may do with `Perl`:

```
perl -pi -e 's/^/#/ if index($_, "deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.4.0 _S") + 1' /etc/apt/sources.list
```